# Help Black Screen problem after ubuntu loading

Tags: 13.10

I am trying to install Ubuntu and after loading my laptop monitor turns off.And the USB is still flashing. I am installing it from a SD card using UNetBooting its better then others because I don't have a CD drive "UEFI laptop Win 8.1 preintalled")

- CPU: AMD A6 APU 5200 Quad-Core with Raedon 8600 GPU
- RAM: 8gb

And I am booting it from SD Card Reader (SD 8gb).

I tried run it with the noparam, or what ever the command is from grub.

My ISO is 13.10 AMD64

Can someone fix my problem?

Comment: You probably need to the bootloader on the hard disk, as most computers probably can't boot properly from the SD card *(see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromSD)*. It can also be difficult to install alongside Windows 8(.1) ([see also](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069)), and Ubuntu 13.10 [is End Of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), so is [not on-topic here](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Also, what make and model of laptop are you trying to install on?

Comment: Toshiba Satelite M50D-A-103

Comment: And don't worry its on a SD card it recognises it as a USB.I use a Card Reader and it works for TinyCore.

Comment: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) might help.

Comment: You found the same prob. as mine I'll try it out.I will comment if it works or not

Comment: Maybe my problem is 3.

Comment: Nope doesn't work either it just makes it worse (Ubuntu loading sprite disappears) reverted the UEFI settings and now its back.

Comment: Problem istn't solved yet.It still loads into powered off screen.

Comment: Adding the nomodeset and removing the -- parameter shows UI.Thanks.